# I can not get the value of a textbox in my controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*** Hello i have long time trying it  and i dont  get any results, my problem is the next:
 On my controller  i can not get the value of the textbox, but if I put the form and  the textbox out of the loop i get the value.*

** this is my view:**

```
@for (int r = 0; r <= Model.Count-1;r++)
{
    i = i + 1;

    <tr>

         @using (Html.BeginForm("Result","Ruta", new { ruta=Model [r].descrip ,ficha =Model [r].ficha }, FormMethod.Post))
         {
             if (i == 1)
             {
            @Html.TextBox("FechaInicio")

             }

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[r].ruta)


        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[r].descrip)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[r].ficha)

        </td>

        <td>
        <input type="Submit" value="Consultar" style=" height :20px;  font-size:12px; "/>





        </td>

         }
    </tr>
```

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Result(string ficha, string ruta)
        {

            Utility.Fecha1 = Request.Form ["FechaInicio"];
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ficha) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ruta) || string                      .IsNullOrEmpty ( Utility .Fecha1) )
            {
                return RedirectToAction("FichaConduces", "Ruta", new { ficha = ficha, ruta = ruta,fecha=Utility .Fecha1 });



            }
            else
            {
                return View("index");
            }

}
```

Comment: Ok, you have said what your problem is, but what is your question?

Comment: NOTE: what im looking for in this process is get the ruta,Ficha and FechaInicio in the method, and call the view fichaconduce with those parameters

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do the simple way?

Create a view based on view model,
and create textboxs for view model's field in view then you can easily get values you want from the form.

And, when you create textbox it should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(....)`

For example 
ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string MyField1{get; set;}
   public string MyField2{get; set;}

}
```

Then in controller's HttpGet

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction()
{
   var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
   return View(myViewModel);
}
```

in view

```
@model MyViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.MyField1)
   ....
}
```

controller's HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
  //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: i cant not do it like  this, becouse my view is based on a stored procedure and i can get the value of the model, the thing is that, when the textbox is inside the loop doesn give me any value

Comment: does your view have a viewmodel?

Comment: yes, look @model IList < TBWeb.Models.SP_GetALlRoutes_Result >

Comment: no, this textbox will get the date from the user, and then i will make a search with this date and the others parameters, so this textbox is not going to get value from the model, is from the user

Comment: even if you get the value from use you can always have it as a field in viewmodel and use textboxfor, else how do you expect the value to be binded and passed to controller?

Comment: do you  mean that if a make a field and use  this       @Html.TextBoxfor("m=>m.MyField), i will get the value that the user will put there.

Comment: it doesnt work, look what i did. I add a column to my stored procedure select aand update my model, on this way i add a new  field call FechaInicio, but this field keep the value that if bring for the database. Thanks